# I want to compress video in android dynamically

Tags: android-ndk, ffmpeg, android-mediarecorder, video-editing

I have video which contains 700mb(5 min duration) size. I want to reduce the file size to less then 30 mb .

I have go through the [FFMPEG](http://androidwarzone.blogspot.in/2011/12/ffmpeg4android.html)  blog and successfully run the samples. But the problem in that library is, it will take too much of time to compress a video file(146 mb take 20 minute). so looking for a good library or right path to achieve my requirement.

My application support from android api-9 and above.

Comment: You are aware that compressing video is one of the mist computation and i/o heavy things you can do on a smartphone? Yo might find libs that do a bit better, but unless there is hardware support in the device itself for reencoding, I doubt you will find substantial improvement.

Comment: Any how i have successfully compiled and added FFMPEG to my android device. but it did not works in some device which are don't have neon cpu (HTC v one ,Kyocera)  i have posted as new question please suggest me http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29160063/ffmpeg-android-not-worked-in-the-non-neon-cpus

Answer (score 1):

The public APIs for access to hardware video codecs was added in API 16, though it didn't really stabilize until API 18.  See the docs for the [MediaCodec](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaCodec.html) class.  Some examples are available [here](http://bigflake.com/mediacodec/).

For API 9+ you're generally limited to software solutions like ffmpeg.

Comment: I have tried FFMPEG but it takes too much of time to compress.. any other alternate solution is there. Because in whats app it simply do in a minute.

Comment: Any how i have successfully compiled and added FFMPEG to my android device. but it did not works in some device which are don't have neon cpu (HTC v one ,Kyocera)  i have posted as new question please suggest me http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29160063/ffmpeg-android-not-worked-in-the-non-neon-cpus