# FFMPEG android not worked in the non neon CPU's

Tags: android-ndk, ffmpeg, cpu-architecture, neon

I have successfully compiled and added FFMPEG to my android device. but it did not works in some device, which are don't have neon cpu (HTC v one ,Kyocera) can any one suggest me to make that work . I have used the following link to get the ffmpeg build [Link](https://github.com/guardianproject/android-ffmpeg) .Used NDK 10 and platform as 4.6

Comment: set NDK_ABI to x86 inside settings.sh

Comment: thank you for the information I will check and let you know soon

Comment: @samgak This is the issues we get while compile after change it to  x86 "checking for i686-linux-android-gcc... /Desktop/software/android-sample/Ffmeg-files/android-ndk-r10d/toolchains/x86-4.6/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/i686-linux-android-gcc --sysroot=/Desktop/software/android-sample/Ffmeg-files/android-ndk-r10d/platforms/android-16/arch-x86" 
checking whether the C compiler works... no

Comment: sorry I don't know how to fix that. settings.sh definitely looks like it should accept x86 as a setting though: https://github.com/guardianproject/android-ffmpeg/blob/master/settings.sh maybe just find another build script?

Comment: @samgak Ok thanks for the valuable information.

Comment: I have checked with the HTC  one v cpu, it's also ARMv7 so changing in the configuration to x86 may not make any changes.

Comment: for ARM but not NEON, perhaps try changing --cpu=cortex-a8 to --cpu=cortex-a5 or some other value

Comment: No luck when i execute a comment with Kyocera c5155 i got log as exit with 11

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/73409/discussion-between-rakki-s-and-samgak).